# Importing blend file to obj

Tags: export

Why I'm getting this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edImL.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a bug in the .obj exporter. If I'm not mistaken it should be `me.to_mesh_clear()` instead of `bpy.data.meshes.remove(me)` in line 389. Would it be possible for you to create a minimized project file (likely only needs the object 'Cube.004' in it) and upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This has been fixed https://developer.blender.org/D5479